# How to fix error code fixtures in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, software-quality

I get the error code, when i coding fixtures in cypress, and if we want create fixture, we must create 2 files, first file for inizialitation fixtures and second file for main file.

and here is the code for the fixture with the file name data_sauce_demo.json

```json
{
  "username": "standard_user",
  "password": "secret_sauce"
}
```

And here is the spec:

```js
describe('Login with fixture data', function () {
  it('Should try to login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/');
    cy.fixture('data_sauce_demo').then((user) => {
      const username = user.username;
      const password = user.password;

      cy.get('#user-name').type(username);
      cy.get('#password').type(password);
      cy.contains('#login-button').click();
    });
  });
});
```

How do fix solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the fixture extension to the test code. Cypress uses the extension to know that the file contents should be interpreted as `json`.

```js
cy.fixture('data_sauce_demo.json')   // specify file with extension
  .then((user) => {                  // user is an object, Cypress has parsed as JSON
    const username = user.username;
    const password = user.password;
    ...
```

Refer to docs [fixture - Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Yields-Icon-namequestion-circle)

> `cy.fixture()` yields the contents of the file.
> Formatting is determined **by its file extension**.